# Parse JavaScript Date in local time zone

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to parse the value of a `datetime-local` input so the format is `'yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm'`. I want the assumption to be that I'm parsing in the local time zone of the user, i.e. if they enter `09:00` they mean 9am *in their time zone*.

Also *not* just the current time offset, e.g. if the user enters a date in June then they mean daylight savings time regardless of the fact it's now November and DST has ended.

I've tried using regular Date objects and moment.js but the assumption is always that the time zone is UTC.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// dateString is the value from datetime-local
var dateInLocal = moment(dateString, "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm");
```

Comment: The code `moment('2013-06-30T08:00', "yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm").toISOString()` when run in my locale (Europe/London) should return `"2013-06-30T09:00:00.000Z"` (9am UTC) as 30th June is in DST but it returns `"2013-06-30T08:00:00.000Z"` (8am UTC). Presumably because it's not DST today.

Comment: … I should possibly specify that I got that result in Chrome Canary – I haven't checked to see if the behavior is different in other browsers.

Comment: Ok, just for extra weirdness that's the result I get in Chrome Canary's dev tools but your jsfiddle works fine. Not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Works in regular Chrome's dev tools but not in Chrome Canary (same machine). `moment('2013-06-30T08:00', "yyyy-MM-DDThh:mm").toString()` produces `"Sun Jun 30 2013 08:00:00 GMT+0000"` in Canary and `"Sun Jun 30 2013 08:00:00 GMT+0100"` in regular Chrome (the latter being exactly what I want).

Comment: But your fiddle works fine in Canary. This is incredibly confusing.

Comment: @RobFletcher Why did you mark this as the answer if your problem persisted? I have the same issue, also only in Chrome. Did you get anywhere with this?