# Get HTML5 datetime-local exact value

Tags: javascript, date

Try to use this, http://jsfiddle.net/mdg2u4ut and you will notice the hour will be different with what you've set, like in my case

[image: screenshot of linked jsFiddle]

I think it's because of the timezone problem.

I can just hardcoded -8 for the hour variable in my case but that's not the smart way of doing it.

```
    <input type="datetime-local" onblur="formatDate(this.value)" />
<p id="para"></p>
```

my JS

```
    function formatDate(date) {
    if(date){

        date = new Date(date);

  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var format = hours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // making 0 a 12
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + format;
  var output = date.getMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear() + " " + time;

  document.querySelector('#para').innerHTML = output;
}
    }
```

Comment: so you need to get user time

Comment: @sanojlawrence I did, it's not accurate because it's local time.

Comment: @sanojlawrence the setted value must be the same with the printed out value, look at the result in the image above.

Comment: what browsers ur website should be compliant ?

Comment: One option is to use moment.js as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20286598/1299394

Comment: @Aaron The best solution is to use date picker from jQueryUI - all browsers compliant.. no fuss.. would you be open to that ? Writing your own method for Date is always re-inventing the wheel - other libraries are also available. with jQuery Date picker - this would have been easy as $.datepicket.formatDate(value,'pattern)

Comment: I would suggest parsing the date string manually and create a `new Date (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, 0)` with each extracted value. It's tedious, but it automatically sets the timestamp into the local timezone, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getUTC` methods instead. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdg2u4ut/1/)

```
  var hours = date.getUTCHours();
  var minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
  var format = hours < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // making 0 a 12
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + format;
  var output = date.getUTCMonth()+1 + "/" + date.getUTCDate() + "/" + date.getUTCFullYear() + " " + time;
```

Comment: can have cleaner out put? so far the output is this 0011-01-01T22:00
Sun Jan 02 11 06:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
1/1/11 10:00 PM

Comment: You can remove the outputs that I put in. They are only there to demonstrate when the timezone effect gets added and show that it is being removed by using UTC time.

Comment: ah didn't c that, u made my day! I love u!